# How to make chrome print in A4 portrait with 0 margin

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

I am struggling with a print problem that i think might be a bug in chrome.

I want to print in A4 in portrait mode, but i don't want chrome's default margins, headers or footers. To make the page print in A4 portrait, i add:

```
@page {
    size: A4 portrait;
}
```

Which works. To remove margins, headers and footers i add:

```
@page {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Which also works, but if i add them together, it doesn't work at all.

I have added a minimal reproduction of the issue [here](https://codepen.io/simon-hammerholt-madsen/pen/oNJPEQV). Does anyone know if there is a way to fix this? or possibly a workaround?